# How to show last item first in ngFor in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have basic `ngFor` directive for display data from an Array, And i want to show the last item of array at the top and last item of array at bottom of result?

I saw few Questions in here tell not to use pipes on `ngFor`. So how can i achieve this behavior in TypeScript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: angularJS has simple syntax to accomplish this. angular does not. it's best to just sort your array in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `sort` function to your array in code. Or create a dublicate for origin array and sort it instead.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use something in html like if only take last one to first. Updated answer thanks to  @Eliseo' s nice approach.

```
<p *ngIf="list.length>0">{{list[list.length-1]}}</p>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list; let last=last">
   <p *ngIf="!last"> {{item}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: you can use in *ngFor, `let last=last` and `*ngIf="!last"`

Comment: Yes better suggestion to use rather than index @Eliseo . Updated answer related your suggestion